# SP2013 movies won't play in MAC Safari

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am running a SP2013 dev environment on Azure. Everything is working fine apart from not being able to play back videos in Safari for OSX.

Scenario:

1. Upload movie (MP4) into assets library by selecting FILES -> New
   Document -> Video
2. Video uploads ok and default frame 1 thumbnail is created
3. Click on the play icon and nothing happens

However, I also have a SP online account and I can upload and play videos no problem using the same OS/Browser combo.

Note also that everything works fine with Chrome on OSX and IE and Chrome on Windows.

It therefore appears to be isolated to my standalone SP2013 install affecting OSX Safari.

Has anybody else come across this?

Comment: Do you have the flip player installed on your Mac too?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because your video plugin is not supported by Safari browser.

[Try this If you are using Flash video player](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4014920?start=0&tstart=0)

[Try this If you are using Silverlight video player](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3834349?start=0&tstart=0)

SharePoint 2013 does support **Latest version of Safari** as described in this link,

[Plan browser support in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx#supportmatrix)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding - Not sure that'll lead to a fix as the same video files work fine when served from SP 2013 Online. It looks like it might be a permission issue as a login box launches behind the browser when the video is clicked. Others have mentioned similar issues elsewhere but without a fix. Thanks anyway, I will take a look at your suggestions just in case :)

Comment: Ah, so you can view video in safari using SharePoint online but not on premises, hmm, can you check if any other user have gotr same problem

Comment: :) Yes, others have the same issue. 

Was wondering whether it was related to NTLM/Windows Auth as some have suggested. Server sends 401 on click... but only on Mac Safari.

It's a real pain because neither Mac Chrome (plugin nag), Mac Safari (video playback), or Mac Firefox (won't run in 64bit mode) will run SP on the MAC without some major issue or other. Mac matters to us as we service the broadcast market and the Windows/Mac split is probably around 50%.